# Use int rand(void) in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to use the function

```
int rand(void)
```

in assembly.

How do I use it? I want to get a random number between 0 and 20.

How can I do that?

I'm working on a Ubuntu 32 bits OS and using the at&t assembly syntax.
This is a sample of my code, i want it to put a random number between 0 and 20 in the %edx registry.

EDIT:

```
    mov $APPLES_X, %ebx
    mov $0, %ecx
    mov $20, %edx
loop_ax:
    call    rand
    idiv    %edx
    mov %edx, (%ebx)

    add $4, %ebx

    inc %ecx
    cmp NAPPLES, %ecx
    jne loop_ax
```

Comment: You would need to at least specify what CPU architecture you are using, what OS and what compiler/assembler.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that completely. I am using Ubuntu 32 bits. And the at&t syntax. the library are already included. I just want to know how to call the function and how to use the returned value.

Comment: You mean you're trying to implement the function in assembly, or use it?

Comment: This doesn't make all that much of a sense. int rand(void) looks pretty much c-like. Int is an x86 asm instruction and has nothing to do with ' integer '. Also what assembly language are we talking about anyway ? Your question is fairly confusing to me. (Edit : Didn't notice your further explanation as i was writing this comment, sorry.)

Comment: I'm trying to use the function. I know its an C function. I am just trying to understand what to do with the output in the eax registry.

Answer (score 6):

For this kind of question the best thing to do is to let the compiler do most of the work for you. E.g. with gcc you can use `gcc -S` to generate assembler source for a small sample C program which already does what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = rand();
    printf("x = %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Generate assembly:

```
$ gcc -Wall -S -O3 -m32 rand.c -o rand.S
```

and you get:

```
    .file   "rand.c"
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "x = %d\n"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    leal    4(%esp), %ecx
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   -4(%ecx)
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ecx
    subl    $20, %esp
    call    rand
    movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    call    printf
    addl    $20, %esp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popl    %ecx
    popl    %ebp
    leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (SUSE Linux) 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973]"
    .section    .comment.SUSE.OPTs,"MS",@progbits,1
    .string "OspWg"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

So it looks like all you need is:

```
    call    rand
```

and the result will be in `EAX`.

If you want to limit the range of the random numbers to 0..20 then implement this in the C program above, test it thoroughly, and then repeat the above process to generate assembler source with this added functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Your orginal code isn't far off. Keep the following things in mind:

1. `rand()` is a standard library function, so you need to link your program with that or the function isn't found / the executable can't run.
   If you use `gcc` to "compile" your assembly file into an executable, and/or use `gcc` to link the assembler-generated `*.o` file into an executable, all necessary dependent libs will be added as necessary.
   If you attempt to hand-link using `ld ...` you need to find out about all those and specify them by hand.
2. On UN*X, `%edx` is a *scratch register* (caller preserved) that gets overwritten when you make a function call. So you've got to move the `mov $20, %edx` two lines down, do it *after* the `call rand`.
3. Another *scratch register* is `%ecx`, hence you cannot keep the loop counter in `%ecx` unless you save/restore it to/from the stack before/after the `call rand`.
   Move the loop counter to a *nonvolatile* (callee-preserved) register instead, either `%esi`, `%edi`, `%ebp` or `%ebx`. Of course, if you choose to use those registers in your function, you also must add code to save/restore then at entry/exit of your func.

Beyond that, as Paul mentioned, it's always a good idea to learn from compiler output, particularly from *optimized* compiler output in the case of assembly. You don't need to compile-to-asm, simply compile to executable, and run `objdump -d <name of program>` to disassemble the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks alot ! Your answers helped very much! :) The problem is now solved! :)